# Ruby Optimise Object Selection from Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, hash

I have an array objects (Hashes, 200-300 tracks) each with a attributes (Integer seconds). I want to choose a random selection of objects so that the sum of their attributes equal a given value (e.g. 3600 seconds).

I've tried: choosing random object & summing their durations, until the total - average duration is met. Then find a final track that best fits the final "slot". However this seemed a rather awkward way to do it and it doesn't *always* work.

I'm certain there's a better algorithm for such a task, I just don't really know how to phrase my search for it.

Comment: Search for `knapsack problem` may throw up some useful algorithms, although your requirement for randomness may mean you need to adapt them. In practice though this is a computationally hard problem, so algorithms for it may need to do quite a bit of work, or be quite complex compared to the description of the problem. Your solution seems quite reasonable - you could extend it by checking for possible swaps to get closer to target time.

Comment: The random aspect is going to use a lot of extra CPU time.

Comment: "knapsack problem" was the term I was looking for, thanks guys. I'll see if I can piece something together to submit as an answer later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice solution is available here:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1#Dynamic_Programming

This can easily be adapted to my problem.